# How do I get rid of extra instances of firefox and get jupyter notebooks to work?

Tags: firefox, jupyter

When I run it in the base environment everything is fine but when I run it in any virtual environment firefox throws this error:

```
Access to the file was denied

The file at /run/user/1000/snap.jupyter/jupyter/nbserver-6259-open.html is not readable.

    It may have been removed, moved, or file permissions may be preventing access.
```

base environment is leading to:

`file:///home/$USER/.local/share/jupyter/runtime/nbserver-7866-open.html`
I'm not sure why this is different.

`jupyter notebook -V` in base is giving `6.5.4`, and in venv is giving `5.7.8`

I've tried reinstalling firefox from snap and web and somehow it seems I've ended up with three different instances of firefox. I think this because when I go to "default apps" the drop down menu shows [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L80LQ.png)

I tried running `jupyter notebook --generate-config` but the config file it generates does not have a`c.NotebookApp.use_redirect_file =`  line to set `false`

I have also tried

```
jupyter lab clean --all
pip3 install jupyterlab --force-reinstall
```

but alas, jupyter still does the same thing.

How do I delete extra instances of firefox and make sure jupyter behaves the same in virtual environments as base environment?

Update: So I goofed and must have installed jupyter with snap. Ran `sudo snap remove --purge jupyter` Now all my notebooks open wthout snap in their directory. Still not sure how to fix duplicate firefoxes.